# laravel excel getting only current data

Tags: php, excel, laravel

I just started using this excel pakage maatwebsite/excel and I manage to download the excel out. But when creating the excel I run into some difficulties

1. How can I change the date format printed out in excel? I saw people using something like this but why can't mine work?

$sheet->setColumnFormat(array('E' => 'd/m/y'));

2. How to get data that are from today? For example, I have entered some data and save into database and when I download the excel it will only show that data and not the past data. How do I do that?
3. Is it possible to change the title of the excel? For example created_at change to Date

Currently here is my code:

```
 public function downloadExcel($type)
    {

        $data = personal_info::join('qualifications', 'qualifications.user_id', '=', 'personal_infos.id')
        ->select(
          'personal_infos.id',  
          'personal_infos.name', 
          'personal_infos.email', 
          'qualifications.qualification',
          'personal_infos.created_at')
        ->get()
        ->sortByDesc('created_at');
        return Excel::create('test', function($excel) use ($data) {
            $excel->sheet('mySheet', function($sheet) use ($data)
            {
                $sheet->fromArray($data);
                $sheet->setColumnFormat(array('E' => 'd/m/y'));
            });
        })->download($type);
    }
```

Comment: For all your questions, you can do that in a view right? then export that view to excel, @Blade to Excel (http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/blade)

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by I can do it in a view? Do you mean am I able to download the excel or something in my view or am I able to see the data inside my excel? And also for the link you gave, I have read that already and I don't really quite understand it

Comment: If possible, could you give me an example so that I would be able to understand it more clearer? @arunkumar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want today data then add where condition in your query like that :-

```
$todaydate = date('Y-m-d');
$data = personal_info::join('qualifications', 'qualifications.user_id', '=', 'personal_infos.id')
    ->select(
      'personal_infos.id',  
      'personal_infos.name', 
      'personal_infos.email', 
      'qualifications.qualification',
      'personal_infos.created_at')
    ->where('personal_infos.created_at',$todaydate) // or you can use whereDate() of laravel like :- whereDate('personal_infos.created_at', '=', date('Y-m-d'));
    ->get();
```

Yes it is possible to change **created_at** to **Date** you need to give alias like that :-

```
enter code here
$data = personal_info::join('qualifications', 'qualifications.user_id', '=', 'personal_infos.id')
    ->select(
      'personal_infos.id',  
      'personal_infos.name', 
      'personal_infos.email', 
      'qualifications.qualification',
      'personal_infos.created_at as Date') //here you can change the name
     ->where('Date',$todaydate) // then you need to change in where condition also 
     ->get();
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: The changing of created to Date works, thanks a lot !! But I am getting this error, Unknown column 'Date' in 'where clause' when I used the  ->where('Date',$todaydate). I tried replace Date with personal_infos.created_at instead, there is no error but there won't be any data shown. So when I try to remove the where clause there is data so what could be the problem here?

Comment: check that data is there of today date or not @Dkna

Comment: Yup the date is there, i tried doing a dd and it result me in this,  #attributes: array:5 [▼
        "id" => 5
        "name" => "test"
        "email" => "hello@gmail.com"
        "qualification" => "adw"
        "Date" => "2017-11-08 05:19:43"
      ] Without the where clause

Comment: @Dkna today date in 2017-12-04... i think you have no data of this date

Comment: Oh yea, I forgot to add in data hahaha thanks a lot will go and add in data now

Comment: yes these small things you need to take care of @Dkna

Comment: Yup, but after changing the date, nothing is showing as well, why is this happening? Here is the dd result,  #attributes: array:5 [▼
        "id" => 1
        "name" => "test1"
        "email" => "hello@gmail.com"
        "qualification" => "ad"
        "Date" => "2017-12-04 04:39:25"
      ]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160394/discussion-between-kunal-and-dkna).